# How to exclude record like WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to exclude records which include keywords stored in exclusion_list table. 
In typical DB, we can do this by using WHERE NOT EXISTS phrase like below;

```
SELECT datetime, server, page, uniq_id, client_req, domain, search_keyword
FROM apache_log a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 0 FROM exclusion_list e WHERE regexp_like(a.client_req, e.ex_url))
```

Is there a way of achieving the same in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing i can find to a `SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS` in the bigquery documentation is the `SELECT WHERE NOT IN` clause.

```
SELECT datetime, server, page, uniq_id, client_req, domain, search_keyword
FROM apache_log a
WHERE NOT IN 
  (SELECT 0 FROM exclusion_list e WHERE regexp_like(a.client_req, e.ex_url))
```

According to the documentation it works in a fairly similar way to the SQL `IN` condition works, where each argument is evaluated then or'd with all of the other values.

> Returns true if expr matches expr1, expr2, or any value in the
>   parentheses. The IN keyword is an efficient shorthand for (expr =
>   expr1 || expr = expr2 || ...). The expressions used with the IN
>   keyword must be constants and they must match the data type of expr.

More information [Here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#comparisonfunctions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems BQ doesn't allow WHERE NOT IN. 

Error: Encountered "" at line 3, column 7. Was expecting one of:

Comment: yes it does, the sample in the answer is missing the field that has to be not in... working query: SELECT top(state, 10), COUNT(*)
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
WHERE state NOT IN ("TX", "CA")