# NOT EXISTS in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to implement something like

```
select * from table1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where
                  table1.col1 = table2.col1 and table1.col2 = table2.col2)
```

I am not able to implement this in BQ.
Would appreciate any help on getting this done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude record like WHERE NOT EXISTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407289/how-to-exclude-record-like-where-not-exists)

Comment: The difference is that here semijoin is on two columns, and in the linked question it was on one column. I don't think it is possible to use IN predicate in such case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do such "relational subtract" operation in BigQuery would be something along these lines:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
  ON  table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND table1.col2 = table2.col2
WHERE table2.col1 IS NULL AND table2.col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

Use "NOT IN". From my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408095/132438:

```
SELECT top(state, 10), COUNT(*) 
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
WHERE state NOT IN ("TX", "CA"
```

Comment: The example in the original question uses correlated EXISTS subquery on two columns, I am not sure it is possible to model with IN predicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Felipe, I did try the solution you gave but that does not work with correlated subquery.